# Azure DevOps - how can I retrieve the history of all my "Name" tags?

Tags: azure-devops, tags

In Azure DevOps you can tag users with `@HisName`. How can I retrieve the history of all the comments where my name was tagged? Please not using emails notifications, but inside the Azure DevOps web site? Thanks!

I've searched and asked a couple colleagues but no ones knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For work items mentioned users in their comment field like this:
[image]

You could try to use 'history' contains 'user name' in a query to get the work item:

[image]

If you mean tag user like this in the tag:
[image]

Since the query doesn't support '@' symbol in the contains field, please don't use @ in the tag or you couldn't query. Then you could query the tag like this and get the work item.
[image]

You could add these date according to your requirement to limit the time:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! First option answered my question :)